# Add ON DELETE CASCADE behavior to an sqlite3 table after it has been created

Tags: sqlite, ddl

Is it possible to add an `ON DELETE CASCADE` to a table after it has been created?

My schema is as follows:

`CREATE TABLE skills(name varchar, skill varchar, level int, foreign key(name) references runners(name), primary key(name, skill));`

And I would like to cascade if the foreign key is deleted.

Comment: Drop the foreign key and re-create it?

Comment: @njk cant drop constraints in sqlite I believe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SQLite's [`ALTER TABLE` command](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) cannot do what you want.

However, it is possible to bypass the SQL interpreter and change the internal table definition directly.
SQLite stores table definitions as a *textual* copy of the `CREATE TABLE` command in its [`sqlite_master` table](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master); check out the result of this query:

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='skills';
```

Add your cascade specification to that string, then enable write access to `sqlite_master` with [`PRAGMA writable_schema=1;`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_writable_schema) and write your new table definition into it:

```
UPDATE sqlite_master SET sql='...' WHERE type='table' AND name='skills';
```

Then reopen the database.

**WARNING**: This works only for changes that do not change the on-disk format of the table. If you do make any change that changes the record format (such as adding/removing fields, or modifying the `rowid`), your database will blow up horribly.