# Is there a common syntax for adding a table constraint to PostgreSQL and SQLite databases?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sqlite

I have an existing table that I want to add a table-level `CHECK` constraint to.

In PostgreSQL, the following is valid:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT myconstraint
CHECK a != b
```

In SQLite, the following is valid:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD myconstraint
CHECK a != b
```

However, the SQLite version doesn't work on PostgreSQL, and vice versa; they fail with a syntax error. Is there a syntax for doing this that works on both?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.1 and SQLite 3.14.0.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your architecture and how you are using these two databases together?  Android app + Java web app in the backend?

Comment: I'm not using them _together_; I'm writing something that needs to be database-independent. Specifically, a reusable Django app; the SQL is going in a `RunSQL` migration operation.

Comment: I'm not sure that the SQLite variant does what you think it does. From [their docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) it seems that the later query will add a column named `myconstraint` & adds a column-constraint for that new column (and not a table-constraint). Unfortunately, I cannot test that.

Comment: @pozs It does what I think it does, I tested before posting :)

Comment: @pozs On closer inspection, you're right; while it has the _effect_ I expected, it does indeed add a third column!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite command adds a column named `myconstraint`, with no data type, and a column constraint `CHECK a != b` (which needs parentheses to be valid).

SQLite's ALTER TABLE cannot add a table constraint. (The [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13154958/11654) is even less portable.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a common way using `alter table add <constraint>`.  One database requires the keyword `constraint` and the other does not allow it.

Can you do this as a column-based constraint?  Both databases accept:

```
create table t (
    x int check (x > 0)
);
```

You should be able to alter an existing column or add a new one with similar syntax.

Comment: Typically if you want database agnostic support while programming, you would use an ORM tool.  In Java, Hibernate might cover your needs, not sure about Django.

Comment: Django has a built in ORM, but it doesn't currently support `CHECK` constraints unfortunately.