# How to temporarily break column uniqueness in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, unique

I've got a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE ChecklistStep (
    Checklist INTEGER REFERENCES Checklist (Id), 
    Id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    StepIndex INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    Name      VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    UNIQUE (Checklist, StepIndex));
```

Now I want to exchange two items' indexes. Doing so I'm breaking temporarily uniqueness of pair (Checklist, StepIndex). I hoped, that I can do that in transaction, such that after committing, all constraints will be kept, but this doesn't work:

```
begin transaction;
update ChecklistStep set StepIndex = 0 where id = 6;
update ChecklistStep set StepIndex = 1 where id = 5;
commit transaction;
```

Causes:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: ChecklistStep.Checklist, ChecklistStep.StepIndex
```

How to write such update?

Comment: Usually you would drop/add the constraint but you can't do that with SQLite, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884787/how-do-i-drop-a-constraint-from-a-sqlite-3-6-21-table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLite does not have deferred UNIQUE constraints.

The [PRAGMA writable_schema dirty trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150075/add-on-delete-cascade-behavior-to-an-sqlite3-table-after-it-has-been-created) does not work here because the internal index would get corrupted if you changed the table without updating the index.

The only way to do this is to use a temporary value that is guaranteed to be unused:

```
begin;
update ChecklistStep set StepIndex = -99999999 where id = 6;
update ChecklistStep set StepIndex = 1 where id = 5;
update ChecklistStep set StepIndex = 0 where id = 6;
commit;
```

Comment: To make things cleaner, I'd also make the column nullable and use null instead of any value. Thanks for the answer, I guess this is the only viable option.

Comment: @Spook If you make the column nullable and add a CHECK against NULL, you can temporarily turn check constraints off using `PRAGMA ignore_check_constraints = ON`, then turn constraints on again, and then maybe `PRAGMA quick_check` (not sure whether this is implied or not by turning checks back on)